# How apply rails scope with order_by and count on some attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I'm using scope in my model like

```
     scope :by_average_rating_than_no_of_rating, :order => 'average_rating DESC,number_of_ratings DESC,editors_pick DESC'
```

But i want to achieve results like below

```
     scope :by_average_rating_than_no_of_rating, :order => 'average_rating DESC,count(number_of_ratings) DESC,editors_pick DESC'
```

How i can apply count on model attribute in order by?

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Try `(count(number_of_ratings.id) DESC)`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the select statement to count the number of ratings.

Here is an example of How i getting,

```
class Song
  has_many :listens
  scope :top5,
    select("songs.id, OTHER_ATTRS_YOU_NEED, count(listens.id) AS listens_count").
    joins(:listens).
    order("listens_count DESC").
    limit(5)

Song.top5 # top 5 most listened songs
```

Comment: number_of_ratings is an attribute of this model(company). And its type is integer

Comment: exception occurs                                                      PG::Error: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ....* FROM "companies"  ORDER BY average_rating DESC,count(numb...
                                                             ^
: SELECT DISTINCT "companies".* FROM "companies"  ORDER BY average_rating DESC,count(number_of_ratings) DESC,editors_pick DESC

Comment: You can also try to use a select statement to count first as a variable and use that variable here.